# laravel 5 send email with html elements and attachment using ajax

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am stuck on the point where i want to send an email using ajax. Find code below.

```
$user = \Auth::user();
Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($message) use ($user) {
            $message->from('xyz@gmail.com', 'From');
            $message->to($request['to'], $name = null);
            // $message->cc($address, $name = null);
            // $message->bcc($address, $name = null);
            $message->replyTo('xyz@gmail.com', 'Sender');
            $message->subject($request['subject']);
            // $message->priority($level);
            if(isset($request['attachment'])){
                $message->attach($request['attachment'], $options = []);
            }

            // Attach a file from a raw $data string...
            $message->attachData($request['message'], $name = 'Dummy name', $options = []);

            // Get the underlying SwiftMailer message instance...
            $message->getSwiftMessage();
        });
        return \Response::json(['response' => 200]);
```

Now i want to send this email using ajax and upon request complete i want to display message on same page that your message sent successfully.

i found the solution for this, but this is to send plain message directly using `Mail::raw()` function which is working perfectly. But i am not able to attach files here or some html codes.

Any suggestion in this regard.